# Zoom out whole Wordpress Page while maintaining whole width for Headers

Tags: html, css, wordpress, google-chrome, zooming

I am working on a WordPress page and the site overall looks better zoomed out. When I zoom out via Chrome the content gets smaller but the header image still stretches over the whole page. Now I tried to apply this zoom by default via this custom CSS code:

```
html {
zoom: 0.8;
-moz-transform: scale(0.8);
-moz-transform-origin: 0 0; }
```

It creates the desired effect, but the header image does not stretch over the whole width anymore. It is obvious because the site is zoomed out, but I would like to find a way to keep it full width even zoomed out. Is there a way to achieve this?

Edit: I checked and on Safari it looks good, seems to be a problem with Chrome.

Comment: have you tried same style to `body` element? image should be parent of zoomed out element.

Comment: unfortunately this did not work...the header image will still be zoomed out and not scale onto the whole width